# Ajax call on CodeIgniter controller results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 3.x development with Ajax. I have a controller/method which is accessible from my browser. However, when I try to request/call that page with Ajax it seems to always result in a 403 Forbidden-error.

I have searched on various search engines (incl. StackOverflow) which all showed up some similar problems. None of them had a clear solution to my problem and I'm stuck which this for a long time now. I can access pages that do not load using CI with an Ajax-request just fine. It seems to be some problem with my CI configuration.

I first thought of some session-related problem, but after turning of sessions completely in CI it did not work however. Below is some of my code I'm using to make the Ajax-request, which in my opinion is just fine and should work (as it does on non CI-pages).

```
$.ajax({
    url : data_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: pay_load,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: So show us the relevant code...  where is the ajax?

Comment: Thank you for noticing that! I accidentally entered the wrong code.

It appears that CI csrf protection throws this 403 Forbidden error. I know there is an option to exclude some uri's. But I'm not sure if it is safe enough to exclude that uri from csrf protection. Someone knows a bit more about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ajax` `data` **must** include the value of the hidden CSRF token field.  This is the part that gets submitted with the standard form action but is missing when you do the `ajax`.

Comment: Thank you for this! As you can see in my last comment I had just found out on this. The problem I still have is that I also want to make some test-files for this controller which works outside CI. Therefor I cannot use any of CI's functions to create such csrf-token and pass it to the post data. I can however disable csrf protection on that uri, but I don't know if that is safe.

Comment: FWIW, this CSRF `data` is also required when using the `remote` method in jQuery Validate.  Basically, anything that uses `ajax` to access a CodeIgniter URL must include the value of the hidden CSRF token.

Comment: @BenurRoptire, the CSRF token is there for security, so I'm never going to tell you it's "safe" to remove it - that's a matter of opinion.  Research [the meaning of CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) so you can make your own informed decision.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I have now excluded the uri from the csrf protection. One other problem I still have is that the Ajax-request does not appear to be using the same session. The controller that is requested needs the same session as the one you use to start the request.