# 403 Forbidden error using ajax in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am displaying the first name in my `textbox` autocomplete using ajax but my ajax URL is not working. It's every time showing in the network tab

> 403 Forbidden.

I tried ajax URL like this

```
 url:baseUrl + "/index.php/Employee_control/search_with_emp_name",
 url:baseUrl +"/Employee_control/search_with_emp_name",
```

But still showing the same error.

**my .htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**My base URL** is `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';`

**My view**

```
<input type="text" class="form_control" name="employee_name" id="employee_name">
```

**custome.js**

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];


    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#employee_name").keyup(function() {
           var emp_name = $('#employee_name').val();
              $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url:baseUrl + "/index.php/Employee_control/search_with_emp_name",
                   data: {
                      emp_name: emp_name
                   },

                   success: function(html) {
                      alert(html);
                   }
               });
            });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function search_with_emp_name(){
        echo $emp_name = $this->input->post('emp_name');
       $get_result=$this->Employee_model->search_emp_name($emp_name);
       print_r($get_result);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function search_emp_name($emp_name){
          $this->db->like('firstname', $emp_name, 'both'); 
          $query = $this->db->get('tbl_employee');
          $result = $query->result();
        if($result)
            {
              return $result;
            }
            else 
            {
              return 0;
            } 

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax call on CodeIgniter controller results in 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727418/ajax-call-on-codeigniter-controller-results-in-403-forbidden)

Comment: Also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7348383/594235

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

First make sure your you have set csrf token to false in your `config.php`;

```
 $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
 $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
 $config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
```

OR if you don't want to set it to false just pass `csrf_token_name` and `get_csrf_hash` with data in your ajax call
like this :

```
 data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'},
```

*It seems that problem is with your base url so Put this line of code in your header of the page and use `BASE_URL`like this*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     const BASE_URL = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
</script>
<script src="<?=site_url('your-js-path/js/custome.js');?>"></script>
```

Your ajax should be like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#employee_name").keyup(function() {
           var emp_name = $('#employee_name').val();
              $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: BASE_URL+"Employee_control/search_with_emp_name",
                   data: {emp_name: emp_name},

                   success: function(html) {
                      alert(html);
                   }
               });
            });
    });
```

Comment: my custome.js file is outside of the application.

Comment: so what is problem just provide the path as given in my answer

Comment: <script src="<?=site_url('assets/js/custome.js');?>"></script>
It's showing 404 not found

Comment: I just want to know what is the issue with my baseUrl which I added in the script?

Comment: so give the correct path to your file and do you have enable csrf protection in your config.php

Comment: Yes, csrf protection path is True. I set the right path. I think your baseurl script is not working. can you help me with the issue in my base URL?

Comment: that is the problem just  put csrf protection to false

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I use only my base URL and I set csrf protection false and this time it's showing right. It's working. Please update the answer

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your help, upvote from my side. Pradeep I need one more help in the codeignator. I will ask the new question and I will tag you please reply

Comment: sure i will help you if i can

Comment: My issue is, I am able to display the record list and I set view on each list when user click on view the I have to display the full message which will come from database....List are displaying but when I click on popup it's not displaying the message

Comment: obviously you have foreach loop to show your records, loop also your modal within it and give record id as  id of modal making it unique id , then on click call this modal

Comment: Actually, I am getting the output in view source but not displaying in the popup. In the popup, It displays the last record